# dropdown menu css only - width of submenu (no text wrap)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have dropdown menu (css only)

### JSFIDDLE:

[>>> jsfiddle <<<](http://jsfiddle.net/4WwzG/)

### HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML 4 and less</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">TEST 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">TEST 3</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    margin: 100px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.menu ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
.menu ul:after {
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: blue;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul ul {
    background: green; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
}
.menu ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; 
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block; 
}   
.menu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;
}

.menu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink; 
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul ul ul li a { 
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block; 
}

.menu ul ul ul li a:hover {
    background: red;
}

.menu ul ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

As you see at last submenu, they are not as upper menus. They wrap text and shrink (minimal width).

### Q:

1. <del>How to make them equal (**same width as parent**) and **no text wrap** ?</del>
2. How to simplify this menu (parent, children, ul > li etc.) so I **don't need to make new style for each new sub-menu**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just as a note, if you have sub-menus that are 4-level deep then that may not be optimal in terms of user experience.

Comment: those are just for emergency case, because some users are stupid enaught to make 4-level submenus ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - this works great on Chrome:

```
* { white-space: nowrap; box-sizing: border-box; }

.menu {
    margin: 100px auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

/* ULs */

.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    background: green; 
    top: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    list-style: none;
}

.menu > ul {
    background: #efefef; 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

.menu > ul > li > ul {
    top: 100%;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%; 
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    top: -1px;
}

/*LIs*/

.menu  li  {
    float: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow; 
    position: relative;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    float: left !important;
    border: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background: blue;
}

/* As */

.menu a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu ul ul a:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Also, consider this isn't a good practice (User-experience-wise) to have so many sub menus. You should attempt to re-design your UI to match the usage of your website in a way that won't make the user frustrated.